# Security issues of not checking data type

Tags: mysql, security

[image]

It doesn’t check for password type. Password may be defined as 4-digit unsigned ints and if a user attempts to change his/her password to something other than 4-digit unsigned ints, then it may cause errors, correct?

If so, what kind of errors?
just a simple error message or can this be a major security issue?
Can someone buffer overflow attack on this?

Comment: Nice [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d. Exactly what buffer are you worried being overflow? You're opening the door wide for anyone to whatever they want already.

Comment: Hmm let me read the link you gave me to see what you mean by having my door wide open.

Comment: newPassword = '1234', custID = "1' OR 1=1 -- ", there you go, i just pulled a [Bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Questions should be self-contained, without people having to refer to an external link to understand what you are asking.  (Not to mention, posting code as an image is less than ideal.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be a major security issue here! More than just a error message. Read more about SQL Injection. The simple rule is that you should always sanitize any string user input to ensure, yes, proper type, but more importantly, that it's doesn't bypass your intent and hack into your DB.

A simple Google search returns for example [this site](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php).

For .NET, it's better to use `SqlParameter` than concatenate string to form your SQL Query. `SqlParameter` guards you against SQL Injection...

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblUser SET Password = @password WHERE CustomerID=@custID", conn))
{
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("password ", newPassword));
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("custID", custID));
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using parameters instead of string concatenation, it may be subject to sql injection attacks